# libcurl (7.19,7) crashes with _mdns_query_callback on OSX (10.6.8)

Tags: c, macos, curl, exc-bad-access, libcurl

my application crashes using libcurl for some unknown reason. It crashed spontaneously after many loops of the same code while using Guard Malloc.

Libcurl version information:

> curl 7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
>   zlib/1.2.3 Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps 
>   Features: GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Sourcecode:

```
char * process_url(char * url,char * post){
    CURLcode res;
    curl_easy_reset(curl);
    if(curl){
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR,CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.107 Safari/535.1");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,write_to_string);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        if (post) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post);
        }
        ResponseStruct result;
        result.response = malloc(sizeof(char));
        result.response[0] = '\0';
        result.length = 1;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &result);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl); //CRASHED HERE
        if (res) {
            printf("CURL FAILED WITH ERROR CODE %i\n",(int)res);
            return NULL;
        }
        sec_sleep(1); //Prevent passing float limit.
        return result.response;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is the function stack:

```
#0  0x7fff869d22ae in _mdns_query_callback
#1  0x7fff869bfc29 in handle_query_response
#2  0x7fff869bf08b in DNSServiceProcessResult
#3  0x7fff869d1a71 in _mdns_query_mDNSResponder
#4  0x7fff869d0c61 in _mdns_search
#5  0x7fff869cfffc in _mdns_addrinfo
#6  0x7fff869cf059 in search_addrinfo
#7  0x7fff869cea7a in si_addrinfo
#8  0x7fff869ce48d in getaddrinfo
#9  0x7fff831695fc in Curl_getaddrinfo_ex
#10 0x7fff83164a3d in Curl_getaddrinfo
#11 0x7fff8313dda3 in Curl_resolv
#12 0x7fff8313dfb6 in Curl_resolv_timeout
#13 0x7fff8314b225 in resolve_server
#14 0x7fff83150aaf in create_conn
#15 0x7fff83150c08 in Curl_connect
#16 0x7fff8315b817 in Curl_perform
#17 0x100001126 in process_url at main.c:90
#18 0x1000013f7 in cancel_outstanding_order at main.c:158
#19 0x100002aac in main at main.c:554
```

There are no threads used in the program. I checked my data int he debugger and it is fine. libcurl doesn't like something. Are there any solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: The most likely issue is a problem with your passed in URL. How do you generate it?

Comment: The URL is https://api-test.tradehill.com/APIv1/USD/GetBalance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getaddrinfo() is a libc call that your operating system (OS X) provides.

As libcurl uses the exact same name resolve function for many operating systems where it doesn't crash I would say that it indicate that the problem is truly in OS X and not in libcurl.

I've never seen this bug reported though, which is odd if it truly is a bug in OS X but then I also never saw it reported on libcurl. Possibly that would suggest that the problem is rather in your application...

If you can repeat the problem with a stand-alone example program, then providing that to the curl project and ask them (us) to help you debug it could be an idea. If you cannot repeat it with a small program it would be another indication that the problem is rather caused by your application!

Comment: Okay, I'll test it with a small program and see if the error develops. I'll get back to you if anything happens. Thanks.